# Rsync to exclude folder and include certain extensions

Tags: command-line, backup, rsync

Creating a cron job for a nightly back-up.  I have the code working in two permentations, but each does something I don't want it to do.

Here are the contents of my filter list:

```
- .*/

- $*

- ._*

- .*

- /.

- CacheClip/*

- gallery/*

+ *.txt
...more includes...
```

in the following command the filter call is not excluding directories:

```
rsync -vvauih --include=*/ --filter='merge ~/BackUpScripts/rsync_filter.txt' --exclude=* --delete --delete-excluded --ignore-errors --prune-empty-dirs --progress --stats /Volumes/ol01 /Volumes/ol01/_PROJECT_FILES_BACKUP/Volumes/
```

Alternatively, the same command with the explicit include and exclude flags removed while adding `+ */` to the top of the filter list and `- *.*` to the end excludes the directories and only gets the files with called extensions, but also copies all files without extensions. In this case changing the exclude at the end to `*` from `*.*` results in all files and directories being hidden.

In the second option adding a `--exclude=*` after the filter list call also excludes everything so rsync does nothing.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

thanks,

Comment: Please clarify how this is failing. Do you mean that, for example, files in `CacheClip/` are excluded but the directory itself is not?